# synchronize not working java

Tags: multithreading, synchronize

**I'm Using to synchronize lockers to lock two array list:**

```all
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/* This class represents data base model to 
 * be accessed via clients
 */
public class DataBase {

    // Scheduled shows
    private List<Show> shows;
    // Rejected shows
    private List<Show> rejectedShows;
    //Complete this variable: Can be changed
    private static int numberOfShowsToSchedule;
    // Singleton
    private static DataBase _db;
    // Singleton method
    public static DataBase getDatabase() {

        if (_db == null)
            _db = new DataBase();

        return _db;
    }

    // Class constructor
    private DataBase() {
        synchronized(this){
        //synchronized(shows){
        this.shows = new ArrayList<Show>();
        //}
        this.numberOfShowsToSchedule = Constants.maxNumberOfShows;
        //synchronized(rejectedShows){
        this.rejectedShows = new ArrayList<Show>();
        //}
        }
    }

    // Add show
    public synchronized boolean addShow(Show show) throws Exception {
        synchronized (shows) {// the show LOCKER
            if (null == show)
                return false;

            if (numberOfShowsToSchedule <= 0)// there is a place in the schedule
                return false;
            for (Show s : shows)
                // check if the time is show(name) or time is taken.
                if ((show.getStartTime() == s.getStartTime())||(show.getName() == s.getName()))
                    return false;
            numberOfShowsToSchedule--;
            Boolean added;
            added=shows.add(show);
            System.out.println(added+" ** "+show.toString()
                    +"\n"+shows.size()+"# SHOWS: "+shows.toString());
            return added;
            //return shows.add(show);
        }
    }

    // Add rejected show
    public synchronized boolean addRejectedShow(Show show) {
        synchronized (rejectedShows) {// the rejected shows LOCKER
            if (null == show)
                return false;
            return rejectedShows.add(show);
        }
    }

    // Get the number of shows to schedule
    public synchronized int getNumberOfShowsToSchedule() {
                return numberOfShowsToSchedule;
    }

    public List<Show> GetShows() {//only used for info
        return shows;
    }

    public List<Show> GetRejectedShows() {//only used for info
        return rejectedShows;
    }
}
```

**And The Thread:**

```all
import java.util.Random;

public class ViewClient extends Thread {
    public int ShowNmuber;

    public void run() {//The Manager(Thread)
        Random rn = new Random();
        Show tempshow = new Show((rn.nextInt(13) + 8),
                Constants.existingShows[ShowNmuber]);

        System.out.println("->Show Created " + tempshow);
        try {
            if(Controller.getController().addShow(tempshow))
                return;
            while(Controller.getController().getNumberOfShowsToSchedule()>0){
                tempshow.setStartTime((rn.nextInt(13) + 8));
                if(Controller.getController().addShow(tempshow))
                    return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void SetShowNumber(int ShowNumber){
        this.ShowNmuber=ShowNumber;
        //System.out.println("---------------------"+ShowNumber);
    }
}
```

Output:

```js
THREAD NO.1Satrted, 
THREAD NO.2Satrted, 
THREAD NO.3Satrted, 
THREAD NO.4Satrted, 
THREAD NO.5Satrted, 
THREAD NO.6Satrted, 
THREAD NO.7Satrted, 
THREAD NO.8Satrted, 
THREAD NO.9Satrted, 
THREAD NO.10Satrted, 
THREAD NO.11Satrted, 
THREAD NO.12Satrted, 
THREAD NO.13Satrted, 
THREAD NO.14Satrted, 
THREAD NO.15Satrted, 
THREAD NO.16Satrted, 
->Show Created {The americans||20:00}
->Show Created {Arrow||20:00}
->Show Created {Person of interest||18:00}
->Show Created {Criminal minds||19:00}
->Show Created {Revenge||8:00}
->Show Created {Family guy||19:00}
->Show Created {Aria||20:00}
->Show Created {The flash||20:00}
->Show Created {Homeland||8:00}
->Show Created {The following||8:00}
->Show Created {Gotham||18:00}
->Show Created {Agnents of shield||8:00}
->Show Created {American idol||15:00}
->Show Created {Game of thrones||15:00}
->Show Created {Black sails||9:00}
->Show Created {My Friend||15:00}
true ** {Game of thrones||15:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Game of thrones||15:00}]
true ** {Aria||20:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Aria||20:00}]
true ** {Person of interest||18:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}]
true ** {Arrow||20:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Arrow||20:00}]
true ** {Black sails||9:00}
2# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}]
true ** {Family guy||19:00}
2# SHOWS: [{Arrow||20:00}, {Family guy||19:00}]
true ** {Criminal minds||8:00}
3# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}]
true ** {American idol||15:00}
4# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}]
true ** {Agnents of shield||16:00}
5# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}, {Agnents of shield||16:00}]
true ** {Gotham||12:00}
6# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}, {Agnents of shield||16:00}, {Gotham||12:00}]
true ** {The following||19:00}
7# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}, {Agnents of shield||16:00}, {Gotham||12:00}, {The following||19:00}]
true ** {The americans||20:00}
8# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}, {Agnents of shield||16:00}, {Gotham||12:00}, {The following||19:00}, {The americans||20:00}]


==========================================================================
8# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}, {Black sails||9:00}, {Criminal minds||8:00}, {American idol||15:00}, {Agnents of shield||16:00}, {Gotham||12:00}, {The following||19:00}, {The americans||20:00}]
REJECTED SHOWS: []
TIME LEFT TO FILL: 0
==========================================================================
```

**As you see in the output value is replaced with another one, so I thought maybe it's because the sync is not working and locking the ArrayList

Comment: I don't understand what you'd expect to see and why you aren't seeing it.

Comment: "1# SHOWS: [{Game of thrones||15:00}]
true ** {Aria||20:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Aria||20:00}]
true ** {Person of interest||18:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Person of interest||18:00}]
true ** {Arrow||20:00}
1# SHOWS: [{Arrow||20:00}]"
I don't want the shows to run over each other like this, I want them to be added in sync wait so the in the end of the of this part i should have 3 values not one...